# How can I make sure the sound only plays once and doesent bug?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in my character movement script I'm trying to play the jump audio I have when my character jumps. This works just fine but a problem I have is that:
In my game when I hit a enemy object my character movement stops and a menu comes up. The issue here is sometimes I hit a enemy object whilst still  in the air. This causes my jump sound to bug out and constantly replay really quickly creating a really awful noise since when i hit the object my character stops moving in the air.

Just to be clear the issue isnt with hitting the actual enemy the problem is that I have the jump sound to play when I jump and since I die on top of the enemy I assume the jump sounds keep repeating itself because I never actually exit the jump because on death all character movement stops so I'm still stuck on top of the hurdle so the jump never really ends and then a menu comes onto the screen.

my current code for the jumping is:

```c#
if (controller.isGrounded)
{
    // Jumping for pc
    verticalVelocity = -gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        verticalVelocity = jumpForce;
        animator.SetBool("is_in_air", true);
        jump.Play();
    }   
}
```

What would i have to do in here in order to only make the jump.Play(); only play once and not keep repeating itself and making that horrible noise when I die ontop of an enemy object?

Edit: I guess a potential fix could be to mute just the jump sound clip or audiosource once the death menu pops up.

Comment: What does this code have to do with hitting an enemy? Why is it entering here again when you hit an enemy? There's not enough information here to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: The problem is when i hit an enemy which in this case is a hurdle that i need to jump over, if i jump and i collide with the top of the hurdle it causes the player to die on the top of the hurdle., and since i die on top of the hurdle i am stuck in the air constantly which causes the jump soundclip to bugout and replay itself constantly. So hitting the enemy isnt the thing that is causing it. the thing that is causing it is the fact that when i jump i want the jump sound to play and since i die at the top of the hurdle it assumes im still jumping so it just keeps replaying the sound.

Comment: In my case, I would use another variable isDead, set it to true when the player is dead. Then change the first if check like this, "if (controller.isGrounded && !isDead)".

Comment: @ZayedUpal I tried it and I can't seem to make it work.